# python package keep being installed on anaconda

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I've been meaning to use matplotlib on python via vscode, however, whenever i use

pip3 install matplotlib

it immediately downloads it on anaconda and I can't use it on my global python interpreter which is 3.10.4. 64-bit

where it is being downloaded:
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib) (1.16.0)

although I can change the interpreter to anaconda, I would very much like to use it on global as well

Comment: I just solved this by 
"/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip install matplotlib", however, will this occur again if i were to download another package?

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose the correct interpreter?

[image]

If you choose the real environment but pip still install package to the virtual environment, I think you have a chaotic environment. It would be a better choice to rebuild a virtual environment.